# Can I enable sound on both HDMI monitors?

Tags: audio, display, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, playback

I'm using an nVidia GeForce GTX 660 on a Windows 8 Pro machine. I have 2 monitors, exactly the same model, both capable of playing sound through HDMI. They're both currently connected using HDMI (2 separate ports on the graphics card, using "DualView" not cloned).

At the moment I can only set 1 monitor as the default playback device. I doubt this is possible just with Windows but is there some way I can play sound through both HDMI devices at the same time?

Comment: I've had a similar issue, and people keep pointing at Virtual Audio Cable as a solution. It wouldn't work for my specific use case, but it might work for yours.

Answer (score 1):

Tell whatever application you're using to send its audio to the other audio device. This, of course, requires that the software have the ability to send audio to a non-default device; see the software configuration for details.