# Windows 8.1 Gigabyte GTX 750 dual HDMI monitors only 1 plays sound

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am using Gigabyte GTX 750 which supports dual HDMI out. I have both HDMI cords going to my dual monitor setup (one cord per monitor). The monitors have built in speakers that sound decent so I want to use them to play sound. The problem is that I can only get sound to play on one monitor. How can I get the sound through both monitors?

Comment: A similar question  http://superuser.com/questions/607979/can-i-enable-sound-on-both-hdmi-monitors?rq=1

Comment: This happens because each monitor is its own audio device.  You would an audio device that would act as a single device, use the monitors as speakers, and pass the video to them.